# Nodejs Express API with NATS?

Tags: node.js, api, express, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I am trying to build a REST API for my frontend app using nodejs + express + nats.
I have a nats-server running in my terminal.

This is my test code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const NATS = require('nats');
const nc = NATS.connect();
nc.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');
})

nc.publish('foo', 'Hello World!');

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    nc.subscribe('foo', function (msg) {
        res.send(msg)
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

After running test code, localhost:3000 cannot be reached.

I found a similar project on github: https://github.com/georgehaidar/poc-express-nats/blob/master/api.js.

I cant seem to find my error.

Can anyone plz help me figure out what im doin wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've not provided the nats.connect() method with a hostname like the original author does:

```
const nats = require('nats').connect({'servers': ['nats://nats:4222']})
```

Nats Connection documentation:

https://docs.nats.io/developing-with-nats/connecting/specific_server